# Customizing the invite received notification for Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-games

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/matches#adding_participants) states

> If the player does not have the application installed on an Android device, they will be prompted to install the application from the Play Store.

Which is great, but if my app is installed I love to get first dibs on the invite request so that I can display a notification personalized for my game.

Is this possible? For example is there an intent I can register for?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, whenever the user signs into your app for the first time on a device, you make a call to [`GamesClient.loadInvitations`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadInvitations%28com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationsLoadedListener%29) to load the pending invitations that the user has. If you notice that the user has a pending invitation, it's probably because they've just installed the app in response to the invitation, so you can display your customized UI.